# Best way to validate a date string in C#

Tags: c#

I was trying to validate a date read from app.config file using `DateTime.TryParse()` method. However, it returned true when the input was `"12/05/201"`. This was actually a typo, and should have been, `"12/05/2018"`. When I stepped through the code it automatically converted the date to `"12/05/0201"` and returned true. However when I used `DateTime.TryParseExact()`, it correctly returned false for the above input. So, should we always use `DateTime.TryParseExact()`? I am little confused because earlier I used use `DateTime.TryParse()` whenever I had to validate a date string! Both the code is given below:

```
Boolean isValidStartDate = DateTime.TryParse(startDate, out DateTime startDateVerified);

CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");

Boolean isValidStartDate = DateTime.TryParseExact(startDate,"MM/dd/yyyy",enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime startDateVerified);
```

Thanks

Comment: `"12/05/201"` _is_ a valid date though.  So why would you want it to fail on `TryParse()`?

Comment: I m confused how a string of `"12/05/201"` is "automatically converted" to something else.

Comment: You use `ParseExact` when you have an exact format in mind.  If the year 201 has to be represented as 0201 then you need the exact format of yyyy.  Maybe what you want is to also validate the parsed year after the parsing succeeds?

Comment: You  should do what makes the most sense in your case

Comment: I agree with juharr. You can easily validate the date **after** the parsing, depending on which date is valid in your case.

Comment: When I said, "12/05/201" is "automatically converted", I meant the out DateTime startDateVerified value was set to "12/05/0201". Sorry for not being clear. Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The year 201 being invalid is business logic - if you want to have logical safeguards on your imported data (and you should), do them explicitly.  With C# you can easily add an extension method to DateTime if you want, something like

```
public static DateTime ParseDateWithSanity(this DateTime, string date)
{
    dt = DateTime.Parse(date);

    if dt.Year < 1900
    {

      throw BadInputException()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to Validate date depends upon the use case and input data source and its formate

DateTime.TryParse is parsed using formatting information in the current DateTimeFormatInfo object so let's say if you use TryParse "12/05/201" it will return the parsed data according to your current culture settings. Which is "12/05/0201" ie  in date format  "MM/DD/YYYY"

Its always good practice to specify date formate and culture variance while parsing date and use TryParseExact instead of TryParse

(Note: To know about current culture settings you can look for a member of classes CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture)